# Usercontrol performance when using it for generating content

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

Well, I know there is lots of questions about usercontrol performance, my question is perhaps different.

I would like to generate my webpage dynamically and unfortunately creating a code for that is a pain when the code contains lots of DIVs, IMGs and other controls.

Usercontrols has a advantage becuase they are created by markup code and It's easy to add getters/setters. That means I can easily edit my code and also control the content.

These usercontrols only contain HTML code with few controls like Label or Textbox. That's all.

I would like to ask, if my approach is ok. What's your opinion about that ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great article describing some pros and cons on using WebForms versus something like MVC. I've used both and like MVC #tonsupontons better.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/528117/WebForms-vs-MVC

Your question is somewhat of a religious debate however so I don't think there's a good answer. If it works and isn't bloated full of view state nonsense and you don't do things like Unit Testing then WebForms and UserControls work fine and you should not really notice a performance hit one way or another. <= My opinion I think though, with some exposure to MVC, you might find it much easier to do what you're doing

Comment: Thank you for answer. Well, my webpage is working fine, i was just not sure if it's a right way when i move to bigger projects. Anyway, i will check MVC tutorials